# All text Arabic in my browsers turned to be very small and thin - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fonts, text

Arabic font was nice when installed Ubuntu 22.04, like it was the default one, but today it turned to the one below

[image]

[image]

You can see the difference between English and Arabic in smoothing

========================================================

Solution I tried:

- resetting Chrome but it's actully looking the same on Mozilla too
- installed tweaks and changed the font but nothing affected how text in font appears in web browsers